# App manifest Error while uploading webpart in SharePoint On Premise

Tags: sharepoint

Iam getting the below error while trying to deploy SPFX webpart in SharePoint  .We are using SharePoint 2019 On-premise.

When generating the package it does not generate any errors but when I upload it to the App Catalog library it gives me the following errors.

There were errors when validating the App manifest.: Xml Validation Exception: 'The 'IsClientSideSolution' attribute is not declared.' on line '1', position '251'., Xml Validation Exception: 'The element 'Properties' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/2012/app/manifest'
has incomplete content. List of possible elements expected: 'StartPage' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/2012/app/manifest'.'
on line '1', position '342'., Xml Validation Exception: 'The element 'App' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/2012/app/manifest'
has incomplete content. List of possible elements expected: 'AppPrincipal' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/2012/app/manifest'.'
on line '1', position '355'.

Comment: did you solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue and in my case i had installed Sharepoint Server 2016 client components that overrided my appmanifest.xsd file

To solve the issue i installed Sharepoint Online client components

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint-developer/spfx-package-error-in-sharepoint/m-p/1898558